# Data pager is not beign displayed

Tags: c#, asp.net, logic

Hello guys this is my product display page.I have included Datapager control in it.
All the product all displayed in the single page...but the pager control in not displayed for navigating between pages

Here is my code....Need help to fix this code

```
         <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="listView" GroupItemCount="4">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div style="width: 650px;">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder" />
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <GroupTemplate>
            <div style="clear: both;">
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder" />
            </div>
        </GroupTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="productItem">
                <img src='<%# Eval("p_location") %>' height="120" width="120" alt="Not found" />
                <div>
                    <b>
                        <%# Eval("p_name") %></b></div>
                <div>
                    Price: $<%# Eval("p_price") %></div>

            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
            <div class="itemSeparator">
            </div>
        </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <GroupSeparatorTemplate>
            <div class="groupSeparator">
            </div>
        </GroupSeparatorTemplate>           
    </asp:ListView>
    <div class="datapager">
        <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" PageSize="8" PagedControlID="listView" runat="server">
            <Fields>
                <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" />
            </Fields>
        </asp:DataPager>
    </div>
```

CodeBehind c#:

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM p_detail", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
    listView.DataSource = dt;
    listView.DataBind();
   }
```

Comment: is it not showing data at all or just when you click the pages?

Comment: It displaying all data in a single page but the pager control is not displayed for navigating between pages

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an event of that listview.
1. go to the listview property
2. Double click on the event named "PagePropertyChanging". this will create an event such as `onpagepropertieschanging="ListView_PagePropertiesChanging"`
3.source code

```
protected void ListView_PagePropertiesChanging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)

{
    DataPager1.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
    ListView.DataSource = dt;
    ListView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: ok. how many rows do you have and how many pages are showing?

Comment: I have 16 rows in my table...its displaying all the product ..This is the code that i found  <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Datapager1"><a class="aspNetDisabled">First</a>&nbsp;<a class="aspNetDisabled">Previous</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$navigator$ctl00$ctl02&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Next</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$navigator$ctl00$ctl03&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Last</a>&nbsp;</span>              on my page source code...

Comment: this should do the work. you can try it removing your <GroupTemplate>,<ItemSeparatorTemplate>, <GroupSeparatorTemplate>. only layout and itemtemplate is needed